# Servlet 3.0 web-fragment serve static content

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, web-fragment

I have a web-fragment containing swagger-ui used by many web projects (WARs).
The static content of the swagger-ui resides in `META-INF/resources`. Some of the web projects only provide a REST-API and have no own UI.
For this kind of projects the web-fragment works, because the static content is served under `${CONTEXT-ROOT}/*`.
But for projects with a custom UI served under `${CONTEXT-ROOT}/*` I do not know how to serve the swagger-ui for example under `${CONTEXT-ROOT}/api/*`.

Is there any possibility to change where static content of a web-fragment is served in the main web project?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same thing. Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: Hi Paul, I posted my workaround as an answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a solution, rather a workaround. In the parent web.xml I can remap the servlet name of the web-fragment like this:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>swagger</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```